# Typescript: How to convert an array of keys into a union type of objects?

Tags: arrays, typescript, typescript-generics, union-types, narrowing

**1. Array of Strings -> Union of Strings (It works)**

I saw a solution creates a union of string literals from an array of strings.

```
const keys = ["cat", "dog"] as const;

type Keys = typeof keys[number]; // "name" | "age"
```

**2. Array of Strings ->  Union of Objects (Is it possible?)**

My question is if it's possible to create a union of objects from an array of strings?  The code below works, I just want to shorten the `SET_PROPERTY_PAYLOAD` with something like `keyof IObject` and generate a union of object types from there.

```js
interface IObject = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

// Is it possible to shorten this type using typescript's primitives
type SET_PROPERTY_PAYLOAD = 
| {
    id: string;
    propertyName: "id"; // keyof IObject at index 0
    value: string; // IObject["id"]
  }
| {
    id: string;
    propertyName: "name"; // keyof IObject at index 1
    value: string; // IObject["name"]
  }
| {
    id: string;
    propertyName: "age"; // keyof IObject at index 2
    value: number; // IObject["age"]
  };
```

My goal for this is to narrow the type of `value` by inferring from the current value of `propertyName`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [a mapped type.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html)

```
interface IObject {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

type SET_PROPERTY_PAYLOAD = {
    [K in keyof IObject]: {
        id: string,
        propertyName: K,
        value: IObject[K]
    }
}[keyof IObject]
```

This type *maps* over the keys in `IObject` and create a new object type for each key.

`SET_PROPERTY_PAYLOAD` should then be exactly equivalent to your long form version above.

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIHkBGArCCzIDeAUMssACYBcyAzmFKAOYDcpyIcAthDfYyFbs4TXhwCuXTNDYBfYsTABPAA4oAygFEAKgH0ACgCV0+zYe0BNAwEELAGXTWAIsgC8RdmQDaAaXIhkAGsIJQB7GDQsXHwAXRoSMkTEyj4GZgAaTyTkFShQtShlADluMR9M7MSANzgAG3ExDBw8MF8YrPlZL2CwiKbosHagA)

Comment: Wow that was quick. Thank you Alex! I read MappedTypes and initially thought it was only for making new properties `K` inside an object `SET_PROPERTY_PAYLOAD`.

I just realized you could actually still use `[keyof IObject]`. Thank you for this! You're a big help!

Comment: Your assumption is correct. With type logic like this, there is often many steps of transformation, and each type is just one step. Type transformations can be very liquid :)